# White keyboard highlighting in dark mode

Tags: script, design, keyboard-shortcuts, userstyle

### Description

This changes highlighting from using keyboard shortcuts to use white instead of black. [Allows actually seeing the highlighting noticeable in high contrast mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420420).

The userstyle only works for dark mode, it does not have any effect in light mode.

### Installation

You need an extension for managing userstyles, like [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html).

- [For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)
- [For Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/)
- For Opera - the Chrome addon should be compatible with Opera.

With a userstyle manager:

[Direct install (GitHub)](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/userstyles/raw/main/stackoverflow/white-keyboard-highlight-dark-theme.user.css)

[See the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/userstyles/blob/main/stackoverflow/white-keyboard-highlight-dark-theme.user.css)

```css
/* ==UserStyle==
@name         White highlight on dark background
@description  Makes the keyboard selection highlight white when using dark themes
@namespace    https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
@version      1
@author       VLAZ
@license      MIT
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
    body.theme-dark .keyboard-selected {
        box-shadow: 15px 15px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) inset;
    }
}
```

### Examples

#### Regular dark mode

##### Before

[image: Dark mode with the second of four questions selected. The dark highlighting is hard to distinguished and makes the question appear "pressed".]

##### After

[image: Dark mode with the second of four questions selected. The white highlighting makes the question pop out more.]

#### High contrast dark mode

##### Before

[image: High contrast dark mode with the second of four questions selected. The black highlight on black background is impossible to see.]

##### After

[image: High contrast dark mode with the second of four questions selected. The white highlight on black background is possible to see.]